# Scripting define symbol code is not skipping the code in unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to skip a particular code by defining scripting define symbol but sadly it is not working.

```
#if VST
using AW.VegetationStudio;

#endif
```

Like in the above code in my project VST is not defined in scripting define symbols but it is still showing error in entering lines.

Comment: what is error? because these lines what you wrote are ok

Comment: Its compiling internal lines, and the script are not available

Comment: i mean this "VST" should not be defined at the start of the file, then all lines would be skipped, try to comment #define VST line

Comment: yeah VST is not defined.

Comment: if so, then code should be skipped, you can see this ref: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-preprocessing-commands#

Comment: Are you sure it is not maybe defined in the `PlayerSettings` -> `Other Settings` -> `Scripting Define Symbols` ?

Answer (score 2):

As of 2021.3.1f1, I had a similar issue with *Scripting Define Symbols*. So, I leave workarounds I found here. (The following things are observed on macOS 12.3.1, by the way.)

#### Unity Editor Behaviours

what I can see with *Project Settings view* - *Scripting Define Symbols section* on Unity Editor is that every time clicking on the Apply button under the input field, the second last edit is reflected on the  in *csproj files*, which is where VS reads the defined symbols from.

However, the modification is not saved to `/ProjectSettings/ProjectSettings.asset` file by the Apply button. (*csproj files* are (re)generated based on this file, btw.) The operations that save the change to the `ProjectSettings.asset` file are *[File - Save Project]* from the Unity Editor menu, or restarting Unity Editor.

#### Workarounds

Based on such current behaviours of Unity Editor, there are two ways to make sure the symbol definition updates are certainly reflected on `ProjectSettings.asset` file and all the *csproj files*.

1. Close Unity Editor (changes are saved to `ProjectSettings.asset`)
2. Open Unity Editor (*csproj files* are regenerated)

Or,

1. *[File - Save Project]* or *[File - Save Project]* from the Unity Editor menu (changes are saved to `ProjectSettings.asset`)
2. Press *+* button under *Project Settings view* - *Scripting Define Symbols section* on Unity Editor, and **leave it empty**
3. Click the *Apply button* (*csproj files* are regenerated)

Comment: The reason is the same, but this workaround does not works for me on Windows/Unity 2020.3.18. However, one more thing to try is menu Edit/Preferenses, -> tab External Tools -> button Regenerate Project files. This works for me.